# List of extra files used

Tags: external-files

Is there a way to know the files used to compile a `.tex` file? This should contain things like...

1. Files imported or "included".
2. Graphics like images (cf `\includegraphics` for example).
3. Listing (cf `minted` for example)
4. Lua scripts when LuaLaTeX is used.
5. ...etc

Comment: you could compile with --recorder and then checkthe fls file.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer The `--recorder` ìs a good option for my use case. Great!